# How do I grab files with specific years in the file name?

Tags: python, regex

I have a large directory of files that range from 2009 to 2017. I want to grab only the files that have specific years in the names and concatenate them together: all files that have 2009, 2012 or 2016 in the name for example. I found some starter code that I'e been playing with but I'm pretty sure this is a big mess cause it doesn't work.

```
yearList = [2009, 2012, 2016]

path = 'my_file_path'
for i in yearList:
    s = re.search(i,line)
    if s:
       dfs.append(s)
```

I was also thinking something along these lines would be cleaner

```
any (regex.match(line) for regex in [regex1, regex2, regex3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where is line coming from? and where do you reuse the path? bothi are missing in your code snippet.

You should have a look at python glob for using pattern matching on filesystem: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Maybe something like this:

```
import glob

yearList = [2009, 2012, 2016]
path = "my_file_path"
files = []
for year in yearList:
    files += glob.glob("{path}/*{year}*".format(path=path, year=year))
```

in regards to your comment, that problem isn't solvable in a one-liner with python glob, as it would need some more advanced pattern matching, which glob doesn't support. A regex in combination with listdir might be better, but with glob you could do the following inside your for loop:

```
files += glob.glob("{path}/*{year}_0[1-9]*".format(path=path, year=year))
files += glob.glob("{path}/*{year}_1[0-2]*".format(path=path, year=year))
```

That would match your month pattern as well.

Comment: This works great and I discovered an issue with the files I am pulling. The names are supposed to follow the convention where the last number after the underscore is 01-12 (ex. file2016_01) but a few files drop the zero so it looks like this file2016_4. How can I modify the code above to exclude those? I'm thinking some logic that says if the number following the underscore doesn't start with a '0' or '1' then skip.

Comment: Perfect! That does the job. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this but it's not strictly necessary and regex's might be overkill in your case. Instead, I would use `find`:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

years = [str(x) for x in [2009, 2012, 2016]]
myFiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
filesWithSpecificYears = filter(lambda x: any(x.find(y) >= 0 for y in years), myFiles)
```

I added the code to actually get the file names from a given directory, identified by `mypath` because I didn't see that in your code. What my code actually does is check each string in `myFiles` to see which contain any of the years specified. This is done using `find` inside of `any`. The `filter` essentially removes any values from the list where the lambda is not true.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a clever way of doing this with regexes but here's a simple nested loop that will do the job:

```
import os
year_list = [2009, 2012, 2016]
file_list = os.listdir('some_path')
file_matches = []

for year in year_list:
    for fi in file_list:
        if str(year) in fi:
            file_matches.append(fi)
```

Or with a nested list comprehension (which is much faster and cleaner, and may also be faster than chaining regexes):

```
import os
year_list = [2009, 2012, 2016]
file_list = os.listdir('some_path')
file_matches = [fi for fi in files for yr in years if str(yr) in fi]
```

Since you're dealing with files explicitly, you can also use glob for this:

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join
year_list = [2009, 2012, 2016]
file_matches = []
for year in year_list:
    file_matches.extend(glob(join('some_path', '*{0}*'.format(year))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

yearList = [2009, 2012, 2016]
yearList = [str(y) for y in yearList]

root = 'path/to/directory/with/all/your/files'

with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile)
    for fname os.listdir(root):
        if not any(y in fname for y in yearList): continue
        with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```